# SAS reading csv file

Tags: sas

I have a .csv data file that looks like this:

```
encore,alcore,4072,4072,,L,L,PhonErr
leopard,alligator,14877,14877,0.36,L,H,SemErr
apple,apple,1973,1973,1,L,H,Correct
salary,appliance,7168,7168,0,H,L,Unknown,
diffusion,appreciation,7272,7272,0.04,L,L,PhonErr
umbrella,arrow,6420,6420,0.16,L,H,Unknown
college,attendance,3885,3885,0.56,H,H,SemErr
body,bank,1890,1890,0.02,H,H,Unknown
```

I try to read it into a SAS data set with the following code:

```
DATA test;
infile "PATH.test.csv" dsd delimiter=',';
input target $ response $ rt1 rt2 lsa freq $ imig $ resp_type $;
run;
PROC PRINT data=test;run;
```

When I do so, however, the printed data set only includes the first row and the last row of my csv file. That is, it only displays the lines beginning with "encore" and "bank". These two rows are formatted correctly, but none of the other rows have made it into the data set. There is no error in the log. The log says,

```
NOTE: 2 records were read from the infile "PATH\test.csv".
The minimum record length was 37.
The maximum record length was 256.
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on? I don't understand why this code won't read it in correctly. This is essentially the same code I use every other time I read in a csv file and it has never done anything like this. In fact, using similar code on other csv files works just fine. For some reason, though, it refuses to read in this file.

Comment: Have you tried PROC IMPORT?

Comment: I've tried the same csv-file and code and it works as expected. Is it possible that in your file there is some issue with EOL (end of line) symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *The maximum record length was 256.* note suggest a problem with the end-of-line characters. If you run on Windows and your file is created on unix/linux or a mac you need to add the termstr= option to your infile statement. LF is for Unix, CR is for MAC OS.

```
DATA test;
 infile "test.csv" dsd delimiter=',' termstr=lf;
 input target $ response $ rt1 rt2 lsa freq $ imig $ resp_type $;
run;
```

Se also the [Usage Note 14178: INFILE's TERMSTR= option facilitates reading files between UNIX and Windows](http://support.sas.com/kb/14/178.html) on this topic on the SAS support site.

Comment: This is apparently what the problem was. It is just strange because I have been importing csv files between a Mac and Windows for use in SAS all semester and have literally never had a problem until now. Anyway, thanks a lot!